# Does two MX resgisters solve this?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

My domains is hosted at HostGator
My AD is linked to the Office 365
Every account I create in my AD need an Office 365 licence to work, ans this is OK.

When I create an account directly on the Hostgator webmail (so not at my AD or Office 365) it doesn't work. Doesn't send or receive e-mails.

Can I solve this using two MX records on both sites? Something like:

Priority 0 to Office and 1 to Hostgator (On Office) and
Priority 0 to Hostgator and 1 to Office (On Hostgator)

So it tries first on one and if doens't find the account try on the other?

or am i completely wrong?

Thanks everyone on advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

What you would need in your scenario is that your mail listed MX forwards mails for unknown accounts to your other mail server. This is possible to configure, but as you control neither Outlook365 nor hostgators emails servers it will be tricky.

Comment: So I definetely CANNOT use a Hostgator mail without an Office licence?

Even with access to both DNS reigsters?

Comment: You can - set your MX to them. Then you won't receive the mail in Exchange365.